# For-loop gives only one value when iterating through an array of Vectors (libGDX)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, libgdx

I'm just a beginner, so here's probably some small mistake which I can recognize but yeah... I'm using libGDX library and here's code of my method:

```
public Vector2[] initCollisionStart() {

    int i = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < currentMapHeightTiles; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            if (currentMap[row][col] == 4) {
                i++;
            } else if (currentMap[row][col] == 3) {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    Gdx.app.log("initCollisionStart", "works");

    Vector2[] collisionStart = new Vector2[i];

    for (int row = 0; row < currentMapHeightTiles; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            if (currentMap[row][col] == 4) {
                position.x = col * 40;
                position.y = row * 40;
                collisionStart[i - 1] = position;
                System.out.println("CollisionStart[" + i + "] = " + collisionStart[i - 1]);
                i--;
            } else if (currentMap[row][col] == 3) {
                position.x = col * 40;
                position.y = row * 40;
                collisionStart[i - 1] = position;
                System.out.println("CollisionStart[" + i + "] = " + collisionStart[i - 1]);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    collisionInitialized = true;
    System.out.print("\n");
    for (int z = 0; z < collisionStart.length; z++) {
        System.out.println("CollisionStart[" + z + "] = " + collisionStart[z]);
    }
    return collisionStart;
}
```

and my output looks like that:

```
initCollisionStart: works
CollisionStart[7] = [40.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[6] = [80.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[5] = [120.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[4] = [160.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[3] = [200.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[2] = [240.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[1] = [280.0:5760.0]

CollisionStart[0] = [280.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[1] = [280.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[2] = [280.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[3] = [280.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[4] = [280.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[5] = [280.0:5760.0]
CollisionStart[6] = [280.0:5760.0]
```

and here's my question. Why does EVERY value of this collisionStart array equals [280.0:5760.0] when I use it outside of this double for-loop? I expect it to return same value which was initialized earlier. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help <3

Comment: Btw, the lines inside your `if` and `else if` looks exactly the same. Are you sure that is how it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second double for loop

```
 collisionStart[i - 1] = position;
```

should be changed to

```
collisionStart[i - 1] = new Vector2(...);
```

I am not sure where you are getting position from.
But I assume it is some Vector2 that you assign to **every element** of the Vector2 array.
The entire array is *pointing to the same object*, and hence your output outside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that I have to initialize each Vector object.